# How can I use browser userscripts on my Android phone?

Tags: firefox-for-android, browser-add-ons

I am a passionate Stack Exchange user and I have a lot of userscripts in my desktop Chrome browser, installed with Tampermonkey. I want to use them on my Android phone, is it possible?

Comment: Related: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/242847/how-can-i-install-greasemonkey-tampermonkey-or-similar-in-firefox-android

Comment: Also related: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/229969/how-can-i-use-userscripts-on-firefox-for-android

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Google Chrome on Android so far doesn't support plugins, of which Tampermonkey is necessary to run userscripts, so here I recommend [Firefox for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mozilla.firefox). You can install [Tampermonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/android/addon/tampermonkey/) addon in Firefox and then start with your favorite scripts. Note that all userscripts are not compatible with Tampermonkey such as  [SE-AutoReviewComments](https://github.com/Benjol/SE-AutoReviewComments) for which you need 
[USI- Unified Script Injector](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/android/addon/userunified-script-injector/) addon.

#### Where can I find scripts to play with?

[Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com) is a Q&A site for apps, scripts, and development with the Stack Exchange API. People discuss about developing around SE, and publish their projects there. You can find a lot of userscripts in the [scripts](https://stackapps.com/?tab=scripts) section.

#### One of my scripts isn't working

beeshyams asked me this question before, but I wasn't a Firefox user then, so I installed Firefox fresh and installed that userscript, and found nothing wrong.

When you encounter some issues with userscripts, try removing and reinstalling them, as well as clearing/resetting your Firefox addon, and see if the issue resolves by itself. Usually this solves 99% of them.

Comment: There's also [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) which is the original such add-on for Firefox.

Comment: FF 81 (mobile) has disabled the TamperMonkey addon (it's listed as "Not Yet Available"). Apparently it's [in the pipeline](https://github.com/Tampermonkey/tampermonkey/issues/940)

Comment: Firefox doesn't let any other add-on be installed other than those recommended ones.

Answer (score 1):

Tampermonkey or any other userscript manager can no longer be added to Firefox as of writing this answer. It was never even possible with Chrome. However, You can instead install actively maintained android firefox fork [iceraven](https://github.com/fork-maintainers/iceraven-browser) that supports extensions like tampermonkey, greasemonkey etc.

Answer (score 1):

The situation changes all the time, I was using Firefox 68 for that but later versions drop add-on support. And using old version 68 is not very safe.

But hopefully Kiwi Browser took the relay of Firefox for browsing with userscripts on Android:

Since 2021 or so, **I've [been using for months](https://community.metabrainz.org/t/user-scripts-on-mobile/134406/15?u=jesus2099) without problems tons of userscripts with [Violentmonkey](https://violentmonkey.github.io) (open source)** and many userstyles with [Stylus](https://add0n.com/stylus.html) **with [Kiwi Browser](https://kiwibrowser.com)!**

It can install and run also other extensions from the Chrome Store.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with the help of **Xposed framework**.

I am the author of `ChromeXt` which adds support of UserScripts to Android Chrome:
https://github.com/JingMatrix/ChromeXt.