# How can I use userscripts on Firefox for Android?

Tags: firefox-for-android

As of October 2020 I can't seem to find a working add-on/extension for Firefox on Android. [Tampermonkey's page](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tampermonkey/) says the add-on is not compatible with Android, but I think it used to work fine a while back. Is there any way to install userscripts on a current version of Firefox for Android (including beta or developer editions)?

If current versions don't support such extensions, and the only way is to install an older package (not recommended due to potentially unpatched vulnerabilities, I know), which is the latest package version I can use Tampermonkey (or a similar) extension with?

Comment: Related: [How can I install Greasemonkey, Tampermonkey, or similar in Firefox Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/242847/how-can-i-install-greasemonkey-tampermonkey-or-similar-in-firefox-android)

Answer (score 6):

End of August Mozilla has pushed a [new major version of Firefox for Android](https://blog.mozilla.org/blog/2020/08/25/introducing-a-new-firefox-for-android-experience/) that bases on a new web engine.

For an unknown reason for this new version they only allow a very small set of hand selected addons. May be the engine changes were so big that most of the addons now have problems?

It seems like the developers at Mozilla are trying to bring back the full addon support in the [next version which is scheduled for October 22th 2020](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2020/09/29/expanded-extension-support-in-firefox-for-android-nightly/). According to the Mozilla blog the current [Firefox Nightly](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mozilla.fenix) version should already include the mentioned full addon support. May you give this version a try - hopefully it will be able to run Tampermonkey addon again.

Edit 2024: For installing any XPI add-on in Firefox for Android you have to enable the Firefox Debug-Mode by opening the **Settings** -> **About Firefox** and tapping the Firefox logo 5 times. Afterwards the Settings page has the new entry **Install add-on from file**.

Answer (score 1):

You can instead install an actively maintained Android Firefox fork [Iceraven](https://github.com/fork-maintainers/iceraven-browser) that supports extensions like Tampermonkey, Greasemonkey, etc.