# How can I install Greasemonkey, Tampermonkey, or similar in Firefox Android?

Tags: firefox-for-android, scripts

I have Firefox 94.1.2 on a Pixel 3XL with Android 10.
I'm trying to install a user-script extension like Greasemonkey Tampermonkey.

addons.mozilla.org shows these are both available for Android: [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/android/addon/greasemonkey/) [Tampermonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/android/addon/tampermonkey/)

When I open the Add-on menu in Firefox, I see one add-on I have Enabled, and about 15 other "Recommended" (not of interest). I find no way to search for additional add-ons in addons.mozilla.org.

I found [this article](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/229969/how-can-i-use-userscripts-on-firefox-for-android) that said this issue would be fixed about a year ago, but I'm still not able to install add-ons.

[This article](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/find-and-install-add-ons-firefox-android) implies that running Nightly versions of Firefox might allow more add-ons. Is there any other way to install these extensions?

Comment: Tampermonkey is now available on Firefox Nightly and Fennec.

Comment: Related: [How can I use userscripts on Firefox for Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/229969/how-can-i-use-userscripts-on-firefox-for-android)

Answer (score 2):

On Firefox you need to enable the debug menu by going to settings -> about Firefox then pressing the Firefox logo at least 5 times. The same applies to Mull and other forks.

Once you had done that, in settings under addons you now have the option "custom addon collections" where you can enter a name and the id of an user who has the addons you want in their collection.

This is not as simple as it is in desktop and other mobile browsers, and it requires either having a Firefox account or the user id of someone with an account.

Answer (score 0):

With Firefox and Chrome both incapable, the best answer is to install yet another Browser. I chose [Kiwi](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kiwibrowser.browser&hl=en_US&gl=US). From the main menu, choose the Extensions page. Touch the "+(from store)" button - it will take you to chrome.google.com. Searching on Tampermonkey offers "Tampermonkey" "Tampermonkey Beta" and "Clipcopy for Tampermonkey". Choose "Tampermonkey" but do not use the Android "Get it" link - it goes to the Play Store and offers an App, not an extension. Click the link to the [Tampermonkey.net](https://www.tampermonkey.net/) site which contains a link to "Install in Chrome". Select it and it will install in Kiwi.